# FileNotFoundException when using the offline cache of HttpResponsecache

Tags: android, caching

I'm using [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) to enable the response caching (for web requests) in my android app, and the offline cache isn't working.
I'm doing the offline cache as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) tells me to do.

In my Application class, at the `onCreate` method, I'm turning on the the cache with:

```
try {
    long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    File httpCacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "http");
    Class.forName("android.net.http.HttpResponseCache")
        .getMethod("install", File.class, long.class)
        .invoke(null, httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
} catch (Exception httpResponseCacheNotAvailable) {}
```

At my `HttpConnection` class I'm getting the JSON with the method:

```
private String sendHttpGet(boolean cacheOnly) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(getUrlCompleta());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String retorno = null;

    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if(urlConnection == null)
            throw new Exception("Conn obj is null");

        fillHeaders(urlConnection, cacheOnly);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), 8192);
        retorno = convertStream(in);
        in.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();

        if(retorno != null)
            return retorno;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Where the `convertStream` method just parse a `InputStream` into a `String`.
The method `fillHeaders` put an token on the request (for security reasons) and if the parameter cacheOnly is `true`, then the header `"Cache-Control", "only-if-cached"` is added to the request header ( with the code: `connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");`)

The cache works 'fine' (with minor strange behaviors) when there is connectivity and the app hit the web server just to see if there is a newer version of the JSON. When the web server answers "nothing changed", the cache works.

The problem is when I have no connectivity and use the header `"Cache-Control", "only-if-cached"`. In this case, I receive a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.example.com/movies.json`. That is awkward, because the [implementation code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/dbc51de44fe4f9a7f81528204250de32ec405d39/core/java/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.java) of the cache probably stores the response in a file named using a hash function on the request url, and not the url itself.

Does anyone knows what can I do or what is wrong with my implementation?

ps: Above, I said "probably using a hash function", because I was not able to found the implementation of the com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache object (the class that `android.net.http.HttpResponseCache` delegates cache calls). If someone found it, please tell me where to look at :)

ps2: Even when I add a `max-stale` parameter in the `Cache-Control` header, it still doesn't work.

ps3: I obviously tested it on api 14+.

ps4: Although I'm accessing an "https://" URL address, the same behavior occurs when the URL is just a normal "http://" address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with the `max-age` value of the `Cache-control` directive in the response given by my web server. It had the following value: `Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`. With this directive, my server was saying to the cache that the response could be used from the cache even if it was 0 seconds old. So, my connection wasn't using any cached response.

Knowing that max-age is specified in seconds, all I had to do was change the value to: `Cache-Control: max-age=600, private, must-revalidate`! There it is, now I have a 10 minute cache.

Edit: If you want to use a stale response, with the `max-stale` directive of the request, you shouldn't use the `must-revalidate` directive in the response, as I did in my webserver.